# Extract float from text line with sed?

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I am issuing a sed replace on a line, trying to extract a particular floating-point value, but all that appears to be matched is the right-side of the decimal

Text Line:

```
63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546: [Tenured: 1416K->1065K(1536K), 0.0492621 secs] 1922K->1065K(2112K), 0.0513331 secs]
```

If I issue `s/^.*\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\): \[Tenured:.*$/\1/`, my output is:

```
.546
```

I'm wanting the `63.546` out of the line.  Why is the very first `[0-9]*` not matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also match the `]` before the number you want:

```
s/^.*]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\): \[Tenured:.*$/\1/
```

Per comment below, here is a more generic approach, matching a non-digit first:

```
s/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\): \[Tenured:.*$/\1/
```

Comment: I need to keep that context-free though, there are other JVM GC options that may/will put other data there.  I may be able to select all combinations empirically.

Comment: OK, then how about matching any non-digit first.  See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that your .* at the beginning is acting greedy, so it absorbs everything up to the dot, but I could be wrong.

Don't use sed. I gave up on this. perl is a better choice (I was starting to play with it) but the solution with awk beats me. Go for that, unless you really love sed for some particular reason...

Comment: Was thinking that too, but otherwise I'm thinking wouldn't have matched the right-side of the float?  Hmmm...thanks for any help :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting Perl  (much nicer way to do regex stuff) and also your answer is right -- the ".*" is greedy and swallows everything up to the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

use awk instead sed. why bother creating complex regex?

```
$ more file
63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546: [Tenured: 1416K->1065K(1536K), 0.0492621 secs] 1922K->1065K(2112K), 0.0513331 secs]

$ awk -vRS="]" -F":" '$1+0==$1{print $1}' file
63.544
63.546
```

Comment: I LOVE awk.  However this sed snippet is from a long list of actions in a much larger sed script that acts as a poor man's parser generator, a few things that sed can do that leaves awk wanting.

Comment: "a few things that sed can do that leaves awk wanting" -- have you heard of the amazing awk assembler?

Answer (score 1):

As Stefano pointed out, the pattern is performing a greedy match at the beginning of your text input.

If you can use perl, this command works to match your line on standard input:

```
perl -e '<STDIN> =~ m/^.*?([\d]+\.[\d]+):\s+\[Ten/ && print "$1\n";'
```

Comment: That's the problem. I think that sed does not support the non-greedy.

Comment: Good call...  I just removed that solution from above.

Comment: Yes, sed does not support said constructs.

Comment: @Xepoch did the `[^\d]*` help you?

Comment: Just tried both of your updates examples, they all produce the same output as I have above without the left-side.

Comment: do you really, really need sed ? :)

Comment: Yes and no.  I have a sed script file that parses nested GC logs that was written due to ironically the troubles of so doing in awk.  Perl is like speaking a clicking language to me for some reason since I can remember.  The syntax and maintaining OPC (other people's code) confuses me.  That said, it may be time I dust off the old Camel Book.

Comment: Just added a Perl example if it will help get you started.